# Create multiple dataframes from another dataframe in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, data.table, tidyr

I have a dataframe with aggregate data and I want to create multiple dataframes from each row of the main dataframe.

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 7, nrow = 10))
setnames(df, c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7"), c("wait", "check", "stay", "con1", "con2", "con3", "con4"))
df$wait <- c(8, 9, 8, 7, 9, 8, 10, 6, 10, 5) 
df$check <- c(7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 7, 9, 6, 10, 5) 
df$stay <- c(6, 10, 6, 6, 8, 7, 6, 6, 8, 4) 
df$con1 <- c(3, 4, 0, 2, 4, 2, 0, 3, 0, 1) 
df$con2 <- c(2, 3, 0, 2, 3, 2, 3, 0, 3, 1) 
df$con3 <- c(1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0) 
df$con4 <- c(0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 3, 2)
rownames(df) <- c("dep1", "dep2", "dep3", "dep4", "dep5", "dep6", "dep7", "dep8", "dep9", "dep10")
df

          wait check stay con1 con2 con3 con4
    dep1     8     7    6    3    2    1    0
    dep2     9     7   10    4    3    3    0
    dep3     8     7    6    0    0    0    6
    dep4     7     7    6    2    2    2    0
    dep5     9     8    8    4    3    1    0
    dep6     8     7    7    2    2    3    0
    dep7    10     9    6    0    3    0    3
    dep8     6     6    6    3    0    1    2
    dep9    10    10    8    0    3    2    3
    dep10    5     5    4    1    1    0    2
```

This is the first new dataframe manually created from the 1st row of `df`. I can do this manually one by one, but I want to write a loop or function to speed the process - producing multiple new dataframes such as `dep1`, `dep2`, `dep3` ... `dep10`. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
dep1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 4, nrow = 8))
setnames(dep1, c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"), c("wait", "check", "stay", "symp"))
setDT(dep1, keep.rownames = "id")[]
dep1$wait <- 1
dep1[c(1:7), "check"] = 1
dep1[c(1:6), "stay"] = 1
dep1[, symp:=as.character(symp)]
dep1[c(1:3), "symp"] = "cond1"
dep1[c(4:5), "symp"] = "cond2"
dep1[c(6), "symp"] = "cond3"
dep1[c(7:8), "symp"] = "clear"
dep1

   id wait check stay  symp
1:  1    1     1    1 cond1
2:  2    1     1    1 cond1
3:  3    1     1    1 cond1
4:  4    1     1    1 cond2
5:  5    1     1    1 cond2
6:  6    1     1    1 cond3
7:  7    1     1    0 clear
8:  8    1     0    0 clear
```

Comment: In `df`'s dep1 row, we got `wait` = 8, `check` = 7, `stay` = 6. We make a new dataframe with `wait` column of 8 rows with value "1", `check` column of 7 rows with "1", `stay` column of 6 rows with "1"; others got 0 The `symp` column is to gather the remaining columns from `df` (cond1, cond2, cond3, cond4) and assign them into the range of rows. So in `df`'s dep1 row, we got `cond1` = 3, `cond2` = 2, `cond3` = 1, `cond4`; the `symp` column in the new dataframe will have the assgined value `cond1` in the first 3 rows, `cond2` in next 2 rows, `cond3` in next 1 row and the remaining rows got 0.

Comment: For row 4, sum of `cond1`:`cond4` is 8 but you have `wait` as 7. Is that a typo?

Comment: @RonakShah yes! Sorry, `cond4` should be 0, so the sum should be matching the number of `stay` instead. I have amended it.

Comment: Ok...my solution below should work then. Did you try that?

Comment: @RonakShah Thank you so much! I have checked the output and it has matched the output. It looks prefect! Also thanks for the unlist function - I was wondering about it. Again thank!

Comment: @RonakShah The current function is conditioned on creating the rows of `dep1` based on the value of `wait` in `df` - `as.data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 4, nrow = x[1],`. I have several cases now where the value of `wait` in `df` is smaller than the value of `stay` in `df`. This means I should have created the the rows based on the value of `stay` in `df` instead. Is there a way we could create the rows depending on the size of `wait` and `stay` - so we use the one with the bigger value. I amend the `dep2` row in `df` so you can see what I'm trying to say.

Comment: yes, you can just change this part `matrix(0,ncol = 4, nrow = x[1]` to `matrix(0,ncol = 4, nrow = max(x[1], x[3])` So the changed line in function would be : `temp <- as.data.frame(matrix(0,ncol = 4, nrow = max(x[1], x[3])
             dimnames = list(NULL, c("wait", "check", "stay", "symp"))))`

Comment: @RonakShah thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do in base R :

```
apply_fun <- function(x) {
   temp <- as.data.frame(matrix(0,ncol = 4, nrow = x[1], 
             dimnames = list(NULL, c("wait", "check", "stay", "symp"))))
   temp$wait <- 1
   temp$check[seq_len(x[2])] <- 1
   temp$stay[seq_len(x[3])] <- 1
   temp$symp <- rep(c(paste0('cond', 1:4), 'clear'), 
                    c(x[4:7], x[1] - sum(x[4:7])))
   temp
}
```

and then apply it for each row

```
list_out <- apply(df, 1, apply_fun)
list_out

#$dep1
#  wait check stay  symp
#1    1     1    1 cond1
#2    1     1    1 cond1
#3    1     1    1 cond1
#4    1     1    1 cond2
#5    1     1    1 cond2
#6    1     1    1 cond3
#7    1     1    0 clear
#8    1     0    0 clear

#$dep2
#  wait check stay  symp
#1    1     1    1 cond1
#2    1     1    1 cond2
#3    1     1    1 cond2
#4    1     1    1 cond2
#5    1     1    1 cond3
#6    1     1    1 cond3
#7    1     1    1 cond3
#8    1     0    0 clear
#9    1     0    0 clear
#...
#...
```

If you need them as separate dataframes as `dep1`, `dep2` etc. we can use `list2env`.

```
list2env(list_out, .GlobalEnv)
```